# Where is a function continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=0$ when $x$ is irrational and $f(a/b)=1/b$ when $a\in \mathbb{Z}, b\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a$ and $b$ have no common divisor except $1$.  Where is $f$ continuous?

From working on the problem I've concluded that $f$ is continuous at every irrational number and $0$.  Is this correct?  If so, how can I go about justifying it?  I'm in my first analysis course discussing continuous functions.

Comment: Why don't you spell out your argument using the definition of continuous?

Comment: If I recall after all these years, any irrational, and $0$, has a neighborhood in which all rationals have arbitrarily large denominators, so the value of $f$ at these rationals is arbitrarily small. Check if my recollection is correct and you may have a start on a solution.

Comment: (b) Show that f is continuous at every irrational.
(c) Show that f is discontinuous at every rational.

Answer (score 1):

The easy part is that $f$ is *not* continuous at $x$ if $x$ is a non-zero rational. Indeed, this makes $f(x)\ne 0$ whereas $f(\xi)=0$ for any irrational (and these can by arbitrarily close to $x$).

For continuity at $0$, observer that we have $0\le f(x)\le|x|$.

Finally, let $x$ be irrational. Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. There are only finitely many rational numbers $\frac ab$ with $b\le \frac1\epsilon$ and $|\frac ab-x|<1$ and of course they all differ from $x$. Hence we can find $\delta$ with $0<\delta<1$ and such that every rational in  $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ has denominator $>\frac1\epsilon$ and thus function value $<\epsilon$.